# jQuery Create Object Literal Loop

Tags: jquery, object, each, object-literal

I need to loop through a series of DOM elements and create an object literal with jQuery as seen below. I'm guessing this involves the usage of .each, but I'm a bit stuck on what to do next.

```
    '1': {
        'text': 'Maintain Compliance',
        'desc': 'blah',
        'size': 10,
        'color': '#afb0b3'
    },
    '2': {
        'text': 'lorem ipsum',
        'desc': 'blah.',
        'size': 4,
        'color': '#9b9ca0'
    },
    '3': {
        'text': 'lorem ipsum',
        'desc': 'blah',
        'size': 6,
        'color': '#c5c6c7'
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd use `.map()` to create an Array of the objects.

```
var objects = $('.my_elements').map(function(i,el) {
    var $el = $(el);
    return {
        text:$el.text(),
        desc:'blah',
        size:'some_size_property_of_the_element?',
        color:$el.css('color')
    };
}).get();
```

The object returned from each iteration is added to the collection.

This version of `.map()` actually returns a jQuery object, so you need `.get()` to convert to an Array.

---

You could use the other `$.map` to create an Array directly.

```
var objects = $.map($('.my_elements'), function(el,i) {
    var $el = $(el);
    return {
        text:$el.text(),
        desc:'blah',
        size:'some_size_property_of_the_element?',
        color:$el.css('color')
    };
});
```

Notice that the parameters are reversed from the first version. Easy to get caught on that.

---

And by the way, you're not really creating an "object literal". You're just creating an object. "Object literal" is a notation used to create objects.

---

Also, I've assumed by your numeric indices that you want an Array of objects. If the main structure shouldn't be an Array, then it will need to be a little different, like this...

```
var objects = {};

$('.my_elements').each(function(i,el) {
    var $el = $(el);
    objects[ i+1 ] = {
        text:$el.text(),
        desc:'blah',
        size:'some_size_property_of_the_element?',
        color:$el.css('color')
    };
});
```

This starts the numbering on `1` as shown in the question. Though I'd still be inclined to use an Array.

Comment: It works perfectly except for 1 thing. It names my objects "object' instead of a number. I need "object" to have a numerically incrementing name such as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ect.

Comment: Here is a nice visual example of what I have and what I need http://screencast.com/t/fbXme1UTjnL

Comment: Disregard proto junk at the bottom of the image.

Comment: @AshBlue: Which code snippet are you referring to? The first two create an Array, so they will have numeric indices starting at `0`. If you're previewing the results in a console, then you won't see the indices, so you're probably just seeing an `Object` placed by the console for inspection purposes. If you're using the last solution, then you should be getting numeric indices starting with `1`.

Comment: ...looking at the screenshot, yes the first one is an Array with numeric indices. The `Object` just shows that the item at each index is indeed an Object. It isn't the property name. My last solution should give you the indices starting at `1`.

Comment: You just saved Christmas (in a postmodern fashion).